# Выражение «улыбка на лице» — это семантический плеоназм?

Tags: семантика, плеоназм

Выражение «улыбка на лице» — это семантический плеоназм? Если нет, то что это?

UPD 20220718. Предложение целиком:

> Мы сделаем все, чтобы вы ушли с улыбкой на лице.

Comment: Здесь "на лице" как лишнее, лучше без него, оно подразумевается. Хотя с ним не критично (просто не очень). Важно вот что: оно звучит с глаголами, требующими обстоятельство места (вопрос "где?"; "ушли" не из тех).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не думаю, что это плеоназм:
улыбка может быть на снеговике;
улыбка Чеширского Кота может висеть в воздухе без лица;
можно просто нарисовать улыбку (без лица);
улыбка может быть как ")" — без лица (этот символ как губы);
что-то может быть похоже на улыбку;
иногда у негативных персонажей есть дополнительные рты не на лице, например на ладонях, и там может сформироваться улыбка.

Пример: *У него на лице появилась улыбка.*
*У него появилась улыбка.* || А так (без "на лице") уже не звучит. Проблемы со стилистикой.
В Нацкорпусе улыбка либо на губах, либо на лице: [примеры](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?dpp=10&format=html&g=i_doc&kwsz=5&lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&out=normal&p=3&req=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C+%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0&sampling=1&sort=i_grtagging&spd=10&spp=50&sr=1&text=lexform).

Да, в основном улыбка на лице, поэтому просто похоже на плеоназм. Но не всегда же так.

Может быть, вас смущает порядок слов. Но тогда нужно всё предложение.

**Если бы улыбка без лица не считалась улыбкой, то это был бы плеоназм.**

Comment: Классный разбор, но автору стоит все же привести предложение целиком. Потому что могут быть ошибки вроде "Он засиял улыбкой на лице".

Comment: Это да, но обычно такие вопросы без контекста (ничего больше нет). Иначе было бы что-то типа "всё ли тут в порядке?" или "можно ли так сказать?". А тут просто о терминологии. Вот "улыбка на губах" мне уже кажется плеоназмом, ведь не может быть улыбки без губ, улыбка как бы состоит из губ, но оно активно используется и хорошо звучит.

Comment: Да-да, все верно! Я апеллировала к автору, чтобы убедиться, что его сомнение не связано с контекстом употребления оборота.

Comment: Авторы вопросов не получают оповещения о комментариях под ответами, если они не комментировали. Так что лучше комментировать под вопросом.

Comment: "Если бы улыбка без лица не считалась улыбкой, то это был бы плеоназм.". Не всегда. "Улыбка на лице" может по контексту подразумевать какое-то конкретное лицо "Улыбка на этом лице". Последнее же ничего общего с плеоназмом не имеет.

Comment: @user190920 Да, интересный момент.

Comment: UPD. Добавлено предложение целиком.

Answer (score 1):

С улыбкой на лице - это фразеологизм(?) означающий притворную улыбку.

Лицо с улыбкой - это маска с улыбкой надетая на лицо, как у актеров древнегреческого театра.

С улыбкой по жизни - это значит не унывать в трудные моменты жизни, быть оптимистом.

Но фраза "с улыбкой на лице" необходима для придания дополнительного контраста от дисгармонии от выражения улыбки у героя и собственно повествования. Употребляя эту фразу рассказчик обычно демонстрирует неискренность эмоций, чувства спрятанные за улыбкой-маской:

*— Любовь? Любовь с этого дня пошла на убыль. Когда она, как это часто бывало с ней, **с улыбкой на лице**, задумывалась, я сейчас же вспоминал полковника на площади, и мне становилось как-то неловко и неприятно, и я стал реже видаться с ней. И любовь так и сошла на нет. Так вот какие бывают дела и от чего переменяется и направляется вся жизнь человека. А вы говорите… — закончил он. Толстой Л. Н., После бала, 1903*

*Она молча, низко поклонилась ему, ее трогали эти молодые, честные, трезвые, уходившие в тюрьму **с улыбками на лицах**; у нее возникала жалостливая любовь матери к ним. Горький Максим, Мать, 1906*

Что-то из английского:

*It was treachery **with a smile on its face**. Это было предательством с улыбкой на лице.*

*I'm lying to you **with a smile on my face.** Я соврала тебе с улыбкой на лице.*

Comment: "Я соврала тебе с улыбкой на лице." - Во-первых, не соврала, а вру. Во-вторых, continious времена не употребляются с глаголом врать. Английский у вас какой-то совсем поверхностный.

Comment: @user190920 английский у меня очень поверхностный, но мне больше и не надо, пример из контекс реверсо, не я переводил, увы. Я бы перевел: я лгущая тебе с улыбкой на моем лице.

Comment: @user190920 ну и в интернетах примеров с ай эм лаинг предостаточно, и не все они про я лежу, так что правда, это не ко мне с английской грамматикой, мне бы с русской разобраться. 
https://englishlib.org/dictionary/en-ru/i+am+lying.html

Comment: А у нового отвечающего, наоборот, искренняя.

Comment: @oleedd А кто-нибудь видел когда-нибудь у человека, задумавшегося в одиночестве, не искреннюю улыбку? Обманывать-то некого!

Comment: @Василий Просто говорю, что два ответа противоречат друг другу. Мне, например, не приходилось сталкиваться со связью с искренностью и притворством. И поэтому мне не кажется, что это имеет место.

Comment: Вы никогда не видели улыбающихся людей? Вам никогда не улыбалась официантка? Вам нигода не улыбался любящий Вас человек? Скорее  Вы просто не фиксировали внимание на качестве улыбок. Но подробнее об этом в комментарии к моему ответу.   А два ответа противоречат друг другу, потому что, у Буратино интерпретация текста Толстого ложная, а текста Горького может быть ложной. Вспомните Макферсона у Бёрнса.

Comment: @Василий "лицо", это не лицо которое морда лица, поэтому ваша логика тут не поможет, это фразеологизм. В русском есть два понятия лица - личность и личина, вот тут личина, внешность скрывающая истинные намерения, маска.

Answer (score 0):

Плеоназм - это излишество (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_literature/3705/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC):

> ПЛЕОНАЗМ  (греч. «pleonasmos» — «излишество») — термин античной
> стилистики, означающий накопление в речи слов, имеющих то же значение
> и потому излишних: «старый старик», «юный юноша».

Улыбка, улыбка на лице и улыбка на губах - это разные улыбки. Когда человек искренне улыбается, то в мимике задействованы многие мышцы лица, а не только губ. Большинство людей подсознательно отличают искреннюю улыбку (улыбку на лице) от заученного оскала хорошо вымуштренного персонала (улыбку на губах).  А просто улыбка относится ко всем улыбкам без уточнения их качества.
Поскольку слова стол и стул по отношению к слову мебель явно не плеоназм, постольку и словосочетания улыбка на лице и улыбка на губах нельзя назвать плеоназмом.

Comment: Улыбка на губах находится на лице, поэтому не разные. Вы говорите об искренней и притворной.

Comment: С точки зрения грамматики Вы правы, а с позиции семантики нет. Словосочетанием "улыбка на лице" люди обозначают искреннюю улыбку. Словосочетанием улыбка на губах люди обозначают дежурную, привычную улыбку - улыбку по обязанности, то есть не искреннюю. При любом лингвистическом анализе нельзя забывать про смысл слов и словосочетаний, а он определяется не лингвистикой, а реальной жизнью.

Comment: Не сталкивался с таким. Было бы где-то зафиксировано.