# "Руками не трогать": нужно ли слово "руками"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Во фразе «руками не трогать» (например, табличка в музее) первое слово избыточно?

Answer (score 1):

Чем же слово "руками" избыточно?

Трогать – **многозначный глагол**, его по-разному понять можно. Например, **не трогать музейный столик** – это значит использовать его не по назначению.

ТРОГАТЬ,  нсв. 1. к Тронуть. 2. что. Разг. **Брать в руки, перемещать, двигать.** Не трогайте этот стул – он сломан. // **Брать что-л., пользоваться чем-л.** Кто трогал мои вещи? Эту вазу не трогай.

ТРОНУТЬ, -св. 1. кого-что. Прикоснуться к кому-, чему-л. рукой.

Выбран самый **частотный вариант,** что вполне логично. Запрещаемое действие **конкретно** обозначено.

Comment: У словаре Ушакова даже пример с руками есть: *Экспонаты трогать руками воспрещается.* И у Ожегова тоже: *Т. руками что-н.*

Comment: В Викисловаре пример: Ей всего-то и хотелось любоваться красивыми растениями, ухаживать за ними, трогать иногда руками и вдыхать их запахи… Л. Е. Улицкая, «Путешествие в седьмую сторону света», 2000 г.

Comment: Если семантика ТРОГАТЬ / ТРОНУТЬ предполагает только руки (что сомнительно), то зачем конкретизировать «руками»? (В таком случае это плеоназм?) Если семантика ТРОГАТЬ / ТРОНУТЬ предполагает не только руки (например, обобщённое [прикасаться](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) / [прикоснуться](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)), то зачем конкретизировать «руками»? А не руками, что, значит, можно? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: @pmor Может, конечно, в этом сочетании и есть избыточность. Здесь обсуждалось также "пнуть ногой". Просто иногда, такие сочетания закрепляются в языке наподобие фразеологизмов, они частотны и уже не рассматриваются как плеоназм. ИМХО.

Comment: Пришлите ссылку на "пнуть ногой". Поиск выдаёт "Нам не удалось ничего найти по фразе пнуть ногой". Также есть проблема с "[улыбкой на лице](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/467937/195473)".

Answer (score 0):

Тут дело не в грамматике, а в попытке вернуть человека в сознание, оборвав его рефлекторный порыв на корню. Приказ-запрет должен быть сформулирован четко и ясно. Не трогать - ничего конкретного не выражает, оно может лишь указывать что нельзя трогать, а человек не трогает, а щупает, или касается, или гладит, или лижет... Поэтому тут есть более сильное "руками" - "руки прочь!". Руками - выдергивает из размышлений, "как бы потрогать, если трогать нельзя", потому что "руки прочь!" - это вообще нельзя ничем и никак касаться. Но так как музей - культурное пространство, то получается что-то среднее между запретом и "фразой-сообщением" что-то значащей, так что это фразеологизм скорее, а хотели бы написать сообщение, написали бы разрешение: "смотреть глазами!" - вот тогда бы действительно получилась ерунда.

Вывод:

"Руками не трогать!" скорее всего эвфемизация фразеологизма "Руки прочь!", как и "экспонаты трогать руками воспрещается," и прочее. По сути это один и тот же приказ-запрет.